# django-rest-framework browsable API doesn't show login link

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently following the django-rest-api tutorial. In my urls.py, I created the urlpatterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    ...
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
])
```

Now when i call any restricted endpoint in my browser, like 127.0.0.1/rest/api/foobar, I get the Browsable API with a 403 Forbidden, which is totally fine. But there is no login link in the top right corner. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, have you added `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov yes, i have